# How Can I Tell if My struct tm Has Been Left in an Invalid State?

Tags: c++, date, time, c++-chrono, gettime

This is a question about invalid input, *not* invalid formatting. For example given the following code:

```
tm bar;

foo >> get_time(&bar, "%Y-%m-%d");

cout >> bar.tm_year >> bar.tm_mon >> bar.tm_mday >> endl;
```

This is fine if I define: `stringstream foo("2001-02-28 non-leap year");` And has a clear error if I have invalid format such as: `stringstream foo("bad format 2001-02-28 non-leap year");`

But I don't know how to detect if my input was invalid for example:

```
stringstream foo("2001-02-30 non-leap year");
```

In this case `bar` can be read as though nothing was wrong. Is there something I can listen for which will alert me that the input was invalid?

Comment: At a guess, `if (foo >> get_time(...)) {/*use bar*/}`

Comment: @chris Nope that is equivalent to `if(foo.good())` which is only set to false if the *formatting* is invalid, not if the  *input* is invalid. You can typically test on [the cloud Visual Studio compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) but they've been down for a day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned by [Matteo Italia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214671/matteo-italia)'s answer, apart from writing your own Gregorian validator, your only reliable double check is [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime). `tm`s obtained with `get_time` cannot be validated, as fields may and may not be filled out. Consider the following 2 invalid examples:

Doing this: `istringstream("2001-02-30") >> get_time(&bar, "%Y-%m-%d");` results in a result that *would* change when run thorough `mktime`:

> `bar.tm_mday` : 30
> `bar.tm_mon`  : 1
> `bar.tm_year` : 100

While doing this: `istringstream("2001-13-30") >> get_time(&bar, "%Y-%m-%d");` results in a result that *would not* change when run through `mktime`:

> `bar.tm_mday` : 13
> `bar.tm_mon`  : 0
> `bar.tm_year` : 100

In order to have all invalid dates altered by `mktime` we need to read the date in without the use of `get_time`:

```
int year;
int month;
int day;
istringstream foo("2000-13-30");

foo >> year >> ws;
foo.ignore();
foo >> month >> ws;
foo.ignore();
foo >> day;

tm bar = { 0, 0, 0, day, month - 1, year - 1900 };
```

At this point any error in `bar` may be corrected by `mktime` so our actual validation step will be to check for a non-`time_t(-1)` return and compare the modified `bar` *back* to the original values:
**`if(time_t(-1) != mktime(&bar) && bar.tm_mday == day && bar.tm_mon == month - 1 && bar.tm_year == year - 1900)`** if this condition is true then the input to `bar` was valid.

In conclusion, it is possible to validate a `tm` without writing a Gregorian validator, but it is *not* possible to validate a `tm` that has been read in by `get_time`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `mktime` tries to interpret also out-of-range values (i.e. for 2001-02-30 will be interpreted as 2001-03-01), you can do an `mktime` followed by a `localtime`, if you get different values back it means that the original ones were not valid.

Comment: Doing the conversion twice seems like a painfully expensive way to accomplish this, but I suppose it would work.