# Inline ignore in Streams

Tags: c++, stream, inline, istream

Is there a way to ignore characters in C++ inline?

For example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29413535/2642059) I'm reading in:

```
istringstream foo("2000-13-30");

foo >> year;
foo.ignore();
foo >> month;
foo.ignore();
foo >> day;
```

But I'd like to be able to do this all inline:

```
foo >> year >> ignore() >> month >> ignore() >> day;
```

I thought this was possible in C++, but it definitely isn't compiling for me. Perhaps I'm remembering another language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.ignore()` is a member function so it can't be used as a manipulator. It also doesn't have the correct return type and parameter declaration to be usable as one. You can easily make your own though:

```
std::istream& skip(std::istream& is) {
    return (is >> std::ws).ignore();
}

foo >> year >> skip >> month >> skip  >> day;
```

Comment: +1, I was going to suggest the same. But be careful that it mixes *formatted* input (the `>> year` etc.) with *unformatted input* (`ignore()`) while using syntax normally reserved for formatted input only.