# mktime Only Handling Leap Years on Clang?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang, mktime

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33470735/2642059) I proposed that [marihikari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5486965/marihikari) use the standard functionality of [`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) rather than trying to implement his own Gregorian calendar system.

I wrote this function to demonstrate how `mktime` could be used to accomplish this:

```
bool leap_year(int year) {
    tm bar = { 0, 0, 0, 29, 1, year - 1900 };

    mktime(&bar);

    return bar.tm_mday == 29 && bar.tm_mon == 1 && bar.tm_year == year - 1900;
}
```

Testing this with:

```
cout << "2000: " << leap_year(2000) << "\n2001: " << leap_year(2001) << "\n2004: " << leap_year(2004) << "\n1900: " << leap_year(1900) << "\n2100: " << leap_year(2100) << endl;
```

Yielded the correct result in [Clang 3.7.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f61d2c0b6ff9179):

> 2000: 1
>   2001: 0
>   2004: 1
>   1900: 0
>   2100: 0

But an incorrect result in [gcc 5.1.0](http://ideone.com/MWGMTq):

> 2000: 1
>   2001: 0
>   2004: 1
>   1900: 1
>   2100: 1

And an incorrect result in [Visual Studio 2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1973191/mktime-not-correcting-1900-reporting-a-leap-year):

> 2000: 1
>   2001: 0
>   2004: 1
>   1900: 1
>   2100: 0

I assume this is a bug in gcc 5.1.0 and Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime):

> Converts local calendar time to a time since epoch as a `time_t` object. `time->tm_wday` and `time->tm_yday` are ignored. The values in time are permitted to be outside their normal ranges.
>   ...
>   If the conversion is successful, the time object is modified. All fields of time are updated to fit their proper ranges.

`mktime` will return:

> Time since epoch as a `time_t` object on success or -1 if time cannot be represented as a `time_t` object.

It is not specified however what efforts the implementation must make to convert the `tm`. So as long as the time is converted *or* `static_cast<time_t>(-1)` is returned the requirements for `mktime` have been filled.

Meaning that the following function [will work on all platforms](http://ideone.com/fROSIa) that correctly support `mktime`:

```
bool leap_year(int year) {
    tm bar = { 0, 0, 0, 29, 1, year - 1900 };

    return static_cast<time_t>(-1) != mktime(&bar) && bar.tm_mday == 29 && bar.tm_mon == 1 && bar.tm_year == year - 1900;
}
```