# Reading formated date from a file C++

Tags: c++, date, ifstream

So I have this file with multiple dates like this:

```
2.10.2015
13.12.2016
...
```

I'm wondering how to read from this file and store day, month and year into 3 separate integers.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty simple since the stream will read `int` values and you can consume the individual `.` delimiters between them via `char`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// construct stream object and open file 
std::ifstream ifs(file_name.c_str());

// check if opened successfully
if (!ifs) std::cerr <<"Can't open input file!\n";

int year, month, day;
char dot;

// extract date
ifs >> day >> dot >> month >> dot >> year;

// check input format
if (dot != '.') // add ranges for month and days validity
{
    std::cerr <<"Wrong date format!\n";
}
```

The above code could be placed in a (`while`) loop reading the file line by line.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment related to the down vote, so that it can be improved.

Answer (score 5):

Given an `istream foo` which contains the dates you'll want to use [`get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time):

```
vector<tm> bar;
tm i;

while(foo >> get_time(&i, "%d.%m.%Y")) bar.push_back(i);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d963874ac8ff7212)

Of course defensive input is best practice, and doing that can be very challenging for a complex input type like a date. If you're going for that you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29413535/2642059